# Parse string in Python that ends in whitespace

Tags: python

I want to extract a part of a string that starts with a number, but ends with a whitespace.

Here is the string: `"X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 "`
I want to extract `0.8475` and then turn this into float.

I can do that even though I do extract the last whitespace as well (float conversion seems not to care about that) and I also know how to get rid of the left-hand white space. But I was wondering, if there is a smoother way.

```py
value = "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 "
start = value.find("0")
print(start)
s = int(start)
end = value.find("5")
print(end)
e = int(end)
x = value[s:]
print(x)
y = float(x)
```

In my code I then do `[s:]` but I was wondering if I could do `[s:e]` which right now I can't because obviously it would cut off the last digit of the number. I want `e` to be the whitespace, so `[s:e]` is good as it cuts off the whitespace. Any advise?

Comment: Do not use the name `str` as a variable, that masks the built-in type.

Comment: float("X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 ".strip().split(" ")[1])

Comment: As for your last question: `e = value.find(' ', s)` will give you the location of the first space **after position s**

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for specific digits; the DSPAM confidence score is not *always* going to end in `5`! You are processing an email header, which is always going to follow a specific structure. In its simplest form it'll have a *name* followed by a `:` colon, followed by the header value. The name can't contain colons itself, so *all you have to do* is separate out the part that comes after the `:` character.

So yes, you want to use the [string methods Python provides](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Here the best tool is to use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
number = value.partition(":")[-1]
y = float(number)
```

This partitions the header on the first `:` character, and only uses the 3rd (last) element of the 3 that `str.partition()` returns. You already realised that `float()` doesn't care about the white space in the string:

```
>>> value = "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 "
>>> value.partition(":")[-1]
' 0.8475 '
>>> float(value.partition(":")[-1])
0.8475
```

About your own code:

- `str.find()` always returns an integer value, there is no need to turn it into an integer again (no need for `e = int(end)`).
- On slicing: You can always *add* to `e`; so `value[s:e + 1]`. However, in your case you could simply have used *only* `s` and sliced with an open end: `value[s:]`, and so get the remainder of the string from position `s`.
- You *could* use `value.find(":")` and then use the result of that to split out the numeric confidence value, but then you'd have to test for `-1` (no `:` colon found).

I suspect that you are handling email text, however, in which case you could just have the [`email.parser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) take care of *all* header parsing for you, and just ask it for the right header.

So, if you have as tring, you an email message object with the [`email.message_from_string()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string):

```
from email import message_from_string

msg = message_from_string(full_email_text)
confidence = msg.get("X-DSPAM-Confidence")
if confidence is not None:
    value = float(confidence)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from email import message_from_string
>>> full_email_text = """From: santa@northpole
... To: the_responsible_owner_of_this_email_address@example.com
... X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475
... Subject: Attractive offer of shared wealth
...
... Dear ...
...
... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor ...
...
... """
>>> msg = message_from_string(full_email_text)
>>> confidence = msg.get("X-DSPAM-Confidence")
>>> confidence
'0.8475 '
>>> float(confidence)
0.8475
```

Using the library makes sure that can make use of the work other developers have already put into making email processing work correctly. Like the fact that email headers are case-insensitive:

```
>>> msg.get("X-DSPAM-Confidence")
'0.8475 '
>>> msg.get("x-dspam-confidence")
'0.8475 '
>>> msg.get("X-dSpAm-CoNfIdEnCe")
'0.8475 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic solution closer to your attempt:

```
y = float(value[value.find(':')+1:])
```

It simply converts the remaining substring after the first `:` and, of course, only works if the `:` is followed by just one number with optional whitespace around it.

Answer (score -1):

rstrip() function will trim the whitespace in right.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string on a known character and strip the whitespace

```py
string = "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 "
numberString = string.split(":")[1].strip(" ") #'0.8475'
number = float(numberString) #0.8475
print(number)
```

Comment: Why strip only on spaces? What if a tab was used? That's perfectly valid in an email header.

Comment: Besides, `float()` *doesn't care* about leading or trailing whitespace. Don't do extra work where it is not needed.

Comment: And finally, don't use split when all you need is a single partitioning. `str.partition()` is faster.

Answer (score -1):

Well if the format of the text will always be the same as the example you've given, it would be much easier to do:

```
float(str.split(" ")[1])
```

Ps: it's not a good idea to name your variables things that already exist

Comment: Why split on `" "` when `str.split()` would give you arbitrary-width splitting? And why split more than 2 times if you are going to discard both the first element and anything beyond the 2nd?

Answer (score -1):

Since no one has an answer using regex:

```
import re

s = "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 "

ans = float(re.findall('\d+\.\d+', s)[0])
print(ans)
```